# ¿Como puedo crear un campo en un form sin tener que crearlo en un model?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Tengo un ModelForm en el cual quiero agregarle un campo sin tener que crearlo en el modelo ¿como puedo hacerlo?

si se preguntan para que quiero tener un campo en un formulario si no lo voy a enviar al modelo es por que voy a tomar el valor de ese campo en la vista y realizar una operación con el.

aqui el `forms.py`

```
class SimpatizanteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    error_css_class = 'error'
    required_css_class = 'required'
    label_suffix = ':'

    class Meta:
        model = Simpatizante
        exclude = ['validado_por', 'fecha_validacion', 'creado_por', 'actualizado_por']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SimpatizanteForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_method = 'POST'
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'

        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Fieldset(
            'Informacion Basica',
            'tipo_documento', 'num_documento','nombres','apellidos','genero','raza','edad','fecha_nacimiento',
            'grupos_poblacionales', 'ocupacion_profesion', 'nivel_academico', 'situacion_laboral',
            ),
            Div(
                FormActions(
                    Submit('save', unicode(('Guardar')), css_class="btn btn-primary"),
                    HTML("""<a role="button" class="btn btn-default" href="{0}">{1}</a>""".format(
                    'javascript:history.back()', unicode(('Cancelar')))),
                    css_class='btn-group col-sm-12',
            ),
            css_class='row'),
        )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es muy sencillo, Como debes saber, `ModelForm` hereda de `Form`, por lo que se crea de la misma forma que haces como si fuera un formulario sin modelo, aquí un ejemplo:

```
class SimpatizanteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    error_css_class = 'error'
    required_css_class = 'required'
    label_suffix = ':'

    # aquí puedes definir campos
    mi_campo_nuevo = forms.CharField(required=False)
    mi_otro_campo = forms.DateField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Simpatizante
        exclude = ['validado_por', 'fecha_validacion', 'creado_por', 'actualizado_por']
```

Y una recomendación que te dejo, es que no uses el atributo de la clase Meta, `exclude`, Ya que en un futuro puede ocacionarte problemas, mejor usa `fields`

Answer (score 1):

No debes usar [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/), solo utiliza [forms.Form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#building-a-form-in-django)

un ejemplo que tome de la [documentación](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/):

```
from django import forms

class NameForm(forms.Form):
    your_name = forms.CharField(label='Your name', max_length=100)
```

Comment: Mójate más y dale cariño a la respuesta :S

Comment: tienes razón, olvide que la gente no entra a la documentacion
solo hace copy paste @DanielDíaz

Comment: Perf, te quito el negativo y te doy positivo !

Comment: Se hace porque los links de fuera se pierden, es mucho mejor meter aquí la info directamente !

Comment: muchas gracias señor

Comment: verdad, no había pensado en eso de los links  @DanielDíaz. lo voy a tener en cuenta para la próxima

Comment: Hola @EdgarAlejandro, gracias por tu aporte, encontre en la documentación que tambien puedo crear el campo heredando de ModelForm:                                                                                          `https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields`